# How correctly pass changeable variable to kotlin class with companion object?

Tags: class, kotlin, android-volley, var

I have some Volley class and when I initialize it from MainActivity I pass `context` and `expectedHosname` values to it:

```
VolleySingleton.getInstance(context, expectedHosname).addToRequestQueue(request)
```

After app start `expectedHostname` can be changed due to user preferences, but `expectedHostname` is always outdated inside class `VolleySingleton` and has startup value. It looks like its compiled with first value and doesn't change when I pass new one through `VolleySingleton.getInstance(..., ...)`.

As I know properties in Kotlin can be declared with `var` keyword and this variable has implicit getter and setter. So I can't understand why `expectedHosname` works like a constant. May be I have to change my companion object..?

**Fragment of class**

```
class VolleySingleton constructor(context: Context, private var expectedHostname: String) {
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: VolleySingleton? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context, expectedHostname: String) =
            INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: VolleySingleton(context, expectedHostname).also {
                    INSTANCE = it
                }
            }
    }

    private fun sslSocketFactory(context: Context, expectedHost: String): SSLSocketFactory {
         // magic with expectedHost var
    }

    //OR
    private val foo: String = expectedHost.toUpperCase()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `expectedHostname` has a setter. But you don't set it anywhere; if `INSTANCE` is already non-null when you call `getInstance`, you just return it. Something like

```
fun getInstance(context: Context, expectedHostname: String) =
    (INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
        INSTANCE ?: VolleySingleton(context, expectedHostname).also {
            INSTANCE = it
        }
    }).also { it.expectedHostname = expectedHostname }
```

will work.